# delete the rows from excel sheet using python

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd, pandas.excelwriter

After getting the data from database into excel file, I want to delete the  rows from that excel. For suppose, I have data like below. By using specific column (source_type) data, I want to delete records before WEQ rows in dataframe (WEQ is excluded)  and again delete records from after WEQ rows in that dataframe (WEQ is shoud be included).

```
input data:

Id_records           filename        source_type  creation_datetime
2was3ed4ff5fds453920vf   sample_product.csv  SL 01-02-2022 13:00
343dfrgregw3klelfsdlk43  Product_data.txt    DS 01-02-2022 12:30
fr2343jergreg340-rger=2r employess.xlsx      WA 01-02-2022 12:19
reg4r32rewfefef3wr3-0     raw_data.csv       ER  01-02-2022 12:14
33rfewf3r32rfefwajsaq     review_data.txt    WEQ 01-02-2022 12:13
 rreg43r23e2eqdrgrg3      sample_product.csv  DF    01-02-2022 12:13
 thhrtg3-20b00bb02223r    Product_data.txt    WS    01-02-2022 12:09
3e12e2refgrg3r223440g3e   employess.xlsx      QWS   01-02-2022 12:09
gdg320t40t8r7gervbr09g    raw_data.csv        RES   01-02-2022 12:08
3r2-gr0gfdb-0480bfdbb     review_data.txt     TRE   01-02-2022 12:08
87efegfbfbbopn32lwfalvl   sample_product.csv  WED   01-02-2022 12:05
10fefefgrbfbsfdov3r3gref4 Product_data.txt    RWS   01-02-2022 12:05
32r4tgtbreg435tqbeqbb5    employess.xlsx      OP        01-02-2022 12:04
dfvbreg43t54ffgeegerg43-  raw_data.csv      WEQ_IVS 01-02-2022 12:04
kbnerogj340t9gue0bttrb    review_data.txt   WEQ      01-02-2022 12:02
t43t34geg3qerbghh5h5      sample_product.csv RQ      01-02-2022 12:02
trh3-h=-htr=4tggkk3k3     Product_data.txt   IC    01-02-2022 12:02
549bjrekggkl33            employess.xlsx    OKL    01-02-2022 12:01
r4g443t34tbt-==43t32rg4   raw_data.csv       FG    01-02-2022 12:01
23r3ttggb9gb34tg43tmhtrh  review_data.txt    LU    01-02-2022 12:01
43t468htj34ppgmo3mbe      sample_product.csv VE    01-02-2022 12:01
```

output data :

```
 Id_records             filename       source_type  creation_datetime
33rfewf3r32rfefwajsaq   review_data.txt     WEQ     01-02-2022 12:13
rreg43r23e2eqdrgrg3      sample_product.csv DF      01-02-2022 12:13
thhrtg3-20b00bb02223r    Product_data.txt   WS      01-02-2022 12:09
3e12e2refgrg3r223440g3e  employess.xlsx     QWS     01-02-2022 12:09
gdg320t40t8r7gervbr09g   raw_data.csv       RES     01-02-2022 12:08
3r2-gr0gfdb-0480bfdbb    review_data.txt    TRE     01-02-2022 12:08
87efegfbfbbopn32lwfalvl  sample_product.csv WED     01-02-2022 12:05
10fefefgrbfbsfdov3r3gref4 Product_data.txt  RWS     01-02-2022 12:05
32r4tgtbreg435tqbeqbb5    employess.xlsx    OP      01-02-2022 12:04
dfvbreg43t54ffgeegerg43-  raw_data.csv     WEQ_IVS  01-02-2022 12:04
```

Comment: Xlwings ?  give it a look : https://www.xlwings.org/

Comment: What happens if you have 3 or more 'SB'? and none?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Using `pandas`, you can filter the first group that matches after the first 'SB':

```
group = df['suffix'].eq('SB').cumsum()
df[group.eq(1)]
```

output:

```
     name     zip addr suffix
2   jones  321234   NA     SB
3  robert  210239   SA     MN
4  Simens  512345   AS     KA
5    John  102910   WA     FQ
6   Smith  901231   QA     KL
```

From excel:

```
df = pd.read_excel('yourfile.xlsx', keep_default_na=False)
group = df['suffix'].eq('SB').cumsum()
df[group.eq(1)].to_excel('newfile.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: @mozaway, I am not getting the expected output whatever you are mentioned. I have got only 2 row.

Comment: can you edit you question and provide the input as dataframe constructor?

Comment: @user98 that doesn't help much ;) The code I provided is working fine on a dataframe copied from your text data. If it doesn't work for you, you should provide a reproducible example (object, excel sheet, etc.), plain explanations won't give us debugging details

Comment: I will provide the info along with excel file pics

Comment: Can you please share your personal email id

Comment: That code snippet is working fine. But, In my case there 400 type of suffixes. then that time it's not working

Comment: @user98 then please provide a more complex example with 2/3 suffixes and the matching expected output

Comment: Can you please share your email.

Comment: You can use one of the countless file sharing provider or use a text example (I don't think the excel format will change much)

Comment: I added the snapcap of input data and output data.

Comment: please use text ;)

Comment: I added as a text.